# SwiftUI Picker data from JSON not displayed

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, picker

I have a picker in swiftui, which i need to fill from a json that i'm currently hosting on my mac.

As I'm running the code, the picker displayed stays empty but the data is available (if I click on a button below which prints it).

Here is my code:

Picker (ContentView.swift):

```
@State var nwm = NetworkManager()

...

Picker("Wähle deine Schule", selection: $selectedSchool) {
    ForEach(0 ..< nwm.schoolList.results.count) {
        Text(self.nwm.schoolList.results[$0].name).tag($0)
    }
}.labelsHidden()
```

NetworkManager.swift:

```
class NetworkManager : ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()

    var schoolList = SchoolList(results: []) {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://jonasmacbookpro.local:8083/IOSApp/getDKSchools") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, _, _) in

            let schoolList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(SchoolList.self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.schoolList = schoolList
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

School.swift

```
struct School : Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var ort : String
    var link : String
}

struct SchoolList: Decodable {
    var results: [School]
}
```

Does anyone know, why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> @State var nwm = NetworkManager()

Use

```
@ObservedObject var nwm = NetworkManager()
```

and instead of

> ```
> var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()
>
> var schoolList = SchoolList(results: []) {
>     didSet {
>         didChange.send(self)
>     }
> }
> ```

use

```
@Published var schoolList = SchoolList(results: [])
```

Comment: This works for a static list, but not for one created from a json file, which is the case i need.

Answer (score 0):

To make the picker refresh is to add a unique id. You can add `.id(UUID())` to your Picker and it should be work fine